# How can I enable metrics on minishift?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-3, minishift, hawkular

My minishift version is v1.16.1+d9a86c9 and I'm running openshift origin 3.9.

I want to use a horizontal pod autoscaler in minishift and for that I need the metrics pods to be installed. I have searched the minishift docs but there's no info about how to install the hauwkular metrics.

Apparently `minishift start --metrics` used to work, but it's not a valid flag anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been removed from Minishift indeed, see https://github.com/minishift/minishift/pull/2241 (and same for the command-line tool `oc cluster up`: https://github.com/openshift/origin/pull/19209 )

However you can still install Hawkular with some extra steps, using the ansible playbook: see https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/install_config/cluster_metrics.html#deploying-the-metrics-components

Answer (score -1):

You can use *-extra-clusterup-flags "--metrics"* with *minishift* now, to pass the flag to *oc cluster up*.

Comment: That flag is broken from some OpenShift releases: https://github.com/minishift/minishift/issues/2447